# Google AdWords Tool showing 0 visitors for a keyword but Google Instant Results showing it. How?

Tags: google-search, google-ads

I tried to Google ‘How to choose best moving company’ but the Google Instant Results showed it automatically in the search box which means that the particular question has been asked by many users (see [this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186610?hl=en)) and when I tried to see the visitors count for that question in Google AdWords Tool, it showed 0 that means no visitors searched that question. My doubt is how Google Instant Search Showing that question and why Google AdWords Tool showing 0 visitors for that?

If you don’t understand my question please see the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "visitors"? Google AdWords is not Google Analytics

Comment: I mean not visitors.. Global Monthly search.. without search how Google Instant search showing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hyphen in Google's Keyword Tool does not mean 0 results, it means the data is either incomplete or the search volume is below 10. It is rather common to discover keywords that do not contain the full search volume data. It is also important to note that it is an estimator and should not be considered 100% correct but should give you an idea.

> If we don't have enough data, you'll see a dash (-). Instead.

Comment: I can only add, that Google Instant changes dinamically, and Google's Keyword Tool may have some delay.

Comment: You undestood me wrong. I only wanted to say, that Google Instant changes dinamically and GKT may not be able to represent it at once.